# How to get the root tag name in enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, tags, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a component whose output depends on a property, ie: props.editable == 'true' : render input otherwise render div

I have tried doing:

```
expect(wrapper.first().type()).toBe('div')
```

but instead I get [Function: ComponentName]

Here is my code:

ComponentFile.js

```js
function ComponentName(props) {
    if (props.editable) return <input />
    else return <div />
}
```

ComponentFile.test.js

```js
it('should render a div if not editable', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ComponentName editable={false} />
    expect(wrapper.first().type()).toBe('div')
})
```

The above test fails because it gets [Function: ComponentName]
I have also tried wrapper.getElement().type but it is also a funcion.

I was able to temporarily get the results I want by doing:

```
expect(wrapper.html().substr(0, 4)).toBe('<div')
```

but I was hoping there was a more idiomatic way

EDIT:
Solved. [Turns out it works if you use shallow instead of mount.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57137891/10526447)

Comment: A better approach to testing the `ComponentName`: https://codesandbox.io/s/function-testing-6sxt5 (check the `__tests__` folder inside of `ComponentName` and also run the Tests tab). I'd also recommend being more specific with your div element by adding a unique className or id. Then you can simplify your assertion to be: `expect(wrapper.find('div.someUniqueClassName').exists()).toBeTruthy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just miss typed there. You should use `.to.equal` instead of `toBe`:

`expect(wrapper.first().type()).toEqual('div')`

Reference:
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/type.html

P.S.:
This will work only if you use `shallow` instead of `mount`, to render your component. Not sure why...

---

### Update:

Matt comments above have a good answer with an example. Posting here for visibility:

https://codesandbox.io/s/function-testing-6sxt5

Comment: Im using jest, and I think the equivalent would be `expect(wrapper.first().type()).toEqual('div')` ? I tried that but got the same result as above. Maybe this is a jest issue?

Comment: Sorry, updated to `toEqual()`. Also, I realized that this is working with `shallow` but not `mount`, not sure why...still investigating that. I included a reference to Matt's comment since I think that was a good answer.

Comment: If using `mount`, you should be able to use `expect(wrapper.children().type()).toEqual('div')` instead.